# Checking out data models in power designer with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, powerdesigner

Through a VBS code I need to check out some data models from the power designer.
The requirements are: Connect to the power designer repository, check out some data models. can anybody help me?

I found this code in SAP documentation, but when i execute it the following error appears.

```
Dim rc : Set rc = RepositoryConnection
'Check out model
Dim TargetModel
Set TargetModel = rc.FindChildByPath("MyFolder/MyPDM", PdRMG.Cls_RepositoryModel)
TargetModel.CheckOut()
Output "Checked"
```

The error messege:

Microsoft VBScript Runtime Error
Required object (0x800A01A8)
on line 5

Comment: You never check to find out if `rc.FindChildByPath` succeeded or not before using `TargetModel`. What do you expect `TargetModel.CheckOut` to do if the `rc.FindChildByPath` did not find anything?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the first comment, at least, verify the FindChildByPath return value:

```vb
Set TargetModel = rc.FindChildByPath("MyFolder/MyPDM", PdRMG.Cls_RepositoryModel)
if targetmodel is nothing then
   output "nothing"
else
   TargetModel.CheckOut()
   Output "Checked out"
end if
```

Apart from that, the sample works for me, and opens the PDM I have checked in.

Comment: Thanks, I identified that the error was in the directory as the PWD repository I have installed does not have this default address.

Set TargetModel = rc.FindChildByPath("Library/Modelo de Dados/CAL", PdRMG.Cls_RepositoryModel)
if targetmodel is nothing then
   output "nothing"
else
   TargetModel.CheckOut()
   Output "Checked out"
end if